# Core Text Performance Problem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-text

I have been following a iOS tutorial on raywenderlich.com, called "How To Create a Simple Magazine App with Core Text" [LINK](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text)

The App works great on the simulator, but when i build it for my iPad 1G, the scroll view is not fluent at all, the performance goes down, and the view becomes useless. 
I have been trying to get help at the raywenderlich.com forum, but with no luck.

Is it a general problem with Core Text or what do you think?

Thansk

Comment: Have you run the app through Instruments to check for leaks?

Comment: I have been trying to look for leaks, but I can't seem to find any. Activity monitor jumps to 100% when scrolling. I am not 100% down with Instruments. Could anyone try to download the source code for th "How To Create a Simple Magazine App with Core Text" App, and compile it? Would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

When trying to debug lag issues, try and find similar apps on the Store that are doing similar drawing. If your performance does not equal that level, then your code can obviously be improved.

For instance today, I was coding a UITableView, but when I ran it - it was not fluid in scrolling. I just *knew* that something wasn't right as the hardware could obviously handle it; looking at scrolling performance in the Music app for instance. So I used the profiler tools and eventually tracked down my error.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment above, I am not an expert at using Instruments. If anyone would try to compile the source code in the tutorial, it would help me a lot. Thanks...